# 2D plane fitting , ransac, matlab, link

Tags: matlab

I have set of 3D points.

```
Points_[x,y,z]% n*3 where n is number of points
```

I want to fit a plane (it is floor) and check height of plane. I think it is 2D problem .

```
z=bo+b1x+b2y;
```

*I can't find a link for 2D ransac plane fitting*. Can someone please give this link or file.

Secondly, Some softwares (commercial)gives  height value of plane. It is mean or some complex value.

Regards,

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. A plane has infinite width and length, but no height. However, here is a 2D RANSAC implementation: http://www.visual-experiments.com/demo/ransac.js/

Comment: Unless he is expecting a lot of bad measurements, RANSAC seems like overkill.  Trusy old linear least squares should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you form the following "A" matrix

```
A = [ones(numel(Points_X),1), Points_X(:), Points_Y(:)];
```

where the `(:)` is to give you column vectors (in case they were not to begin with)

Then you can write your equation as the classic linear system of equations:

```
A*b = Points_Z(:);
```

where b = [b0; b1; b2] -- a column vector of the parameters you are trying to determine.
This has the canonical solution

```
b=A\Points_Z(:)
```

or    `b=pinv(A)*Points_Z(:)`

See help on mldivide and pinv.

You must have 3 or more points which don't all lie on a line.  For an overdetermined system like this, pinv and \ will basically produce the same results.  If they are nearly colinear, there may be some advantage using .

The 3 parameters in b are basically the height of the plane above the origin, the x slope, and the y slope of the plane.  If you think about it, the "height" of a plane IS your z term.  You can talk about height above some point (like the origin).   Now, if you want height at the center of mass of the sampled points, you would then do

```
z_mean = [1 mean(Points_X(:) ) mean( Points_Y(:) )] * b
```

which is probably just equivalent to `mean( Points_Z(:) )`.   For this definition to be meaningful, you would have to ensure that you have a uniformly spaced grid over the region of interest.

There may be other definitions, depending on your application.  For instance, if you are trying to find the height at a center of a room, with points sampled along the walls and interior, then replacing mean with median might be more appropriate.